# Sostenernos de una sombra

Tags: traducción, definiciones, poesía, metáfora

### Spanish

Significado difícil: "sostenernos de una sombra". ¿Se refiere a una sustancia superior?

---

### English

Difficult meаning: "sostenernos de una
sombra". Is it said about а superior substance?

> Roberto Juarroz (Argentina)
>   CUANDO EL MUNDO SE AFINA
>   Cuando el mundo se afina
>   como si apenas fuera un filamento,
>   nuestras manos inhábiles
>   no pueden aferrarse ya de nada.
>
> No nos han enseñado
>   el único ejercicio que podría salvarnos:
>   aprender a sostenernos de una sombra.

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Please, read our [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq) to learn how this site is run. We hope to see you often here!

Comment: "Una luz" podría significar un ser superior, pero "una sombra", difícilmente lo sea. "Sostenernos de una sombra" parece significar la aptitud de conseguir sostén (apoyo, ligazón con la realidad, atadura al mundo real) a partir de lo menos real del mundo real: una sombra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Español

No lo creo. Probablemente, realmente esté diciendo que nos sostengamos de una sombra ya que el mundo se afinó y no podemos sostenernos de él, y por el contrario sería más fácil hacerlo de una sobra. Fíjate en la metáfora y la ironía ya que no puedes sostenerte de una sombra.

---

### Inglés

I don't think so. Probably he's really saying to hold ourselves from a shadow as the world is sharpened and thin and we cannot hold ourselves from it and it would be easier to do it form a shadow instead. Note the metaphor and the irony as you can't hold yourself from a shadow.

Comment: i imаgine an old man when read. The irony and sorrow. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like, learning to support ourselves or some kind of expression indicating we must learn to stand on our on feet.